# Using cgroups v2 without root

Tags: linux, cgroups

On operating systems which use cgroups v2, such as Ubuntu 22.04, I am unable to 'cgexec' any process without being root. This type of code used to work fine, if I use root once to set the permissions to a particular user. I tried it on a recent redhat release and had similar problems.

For example:

```
$ sudo cgcreate -t caj:caj -a caj:caj -g memory:qqq
[sudo] password for caj:
$ cgexec -g memory:qqq ls
cgroup change of group failed
$ sudo cgexec -g memory:qqq ls
<files ...>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the group under your user slice (make sure to use the correct id for the user).

Instead of:

```
sudo cgcreate -t caj:caj -a caj:caj -g memory:qqq
cgexec -g memory:qqq ls
```

Try:

```
sudo cgcreate -t caj:caj -a caj:caj -g memory:user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/qqq
cgexec -g memory:user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/qqq ls
```

Note that from the *cgexec* manual page there is a **CGROUP_LOGLEVEL** environment variable which can be set to **DEBUG**, **INFO**, **WARNING** or **ERROR** that might be useful to see the specific issue such as "No such file or directory" or "Permission denied" and the associated file.

Setting CGROUP_LOGLEVEL to INFO for your command shows:

```
CGROUP_LOGLEVEL=INFO cgexec -g memory:qqq ls

Warning: cannot write tid 2482 to /sys/fs/cgroup/qqq/cgroup.procs:Permission denied
```

You can see the group for your current shell by running:

```
cat /proc/self/cgroup

0::/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-org.gnome.Terminal.slice/vte-spawn-*.scope
```

The kernel documentation for cgroup v2 has a [Delegation Containment](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html#delegation-containment) section which explains that in order to move a process between groups:

> The writer must have write access to the “cgroup.procs” file of the common ancestor of the source and destination cgroups.

and the following example is given:

> For an example, let’s assume cgroups C0 and C1 have been delegated to user U0 who created C00, C01 under C0 and C10 under C1 as follows and all processes under C0 and C1 belong to U0:

[image]

> Let’s also say U0 wants to write the PID of a process which is currently in C10 into “C00/cgroup.procs”. U0 has write access to the file; however, the common ancestor of the source cgroup C10 and the destination cgroup C00 is above the points of delegation and U0 would not have write access to its “cgroup.procs” files and thus the write will be denied with -EACCES.

When you run cgexec it tries to move the ls process from the current group under user.slice as shown above to the qqq group. IIUC the common ancestor would be the root cgroup so you get permission denied.

Using CGROUP_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG you can see that cgexec indicates

> Will move pid 3042 to cgroup 'qqq'

and

> cgroup change of group failed

```
$ CGROUP_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG cgexec -g memory:qqq ls
Found cgroup option cpuset, count 0
Found cgroup option cpu, count 1
Found cgroup option io, count 2
Found cgroup option memory, count 3
Found cgroup option hugetlb, count 4
Found cgroup option pids, count 5
Found cgroup option rdma, count 6
Found cgroup option misc, count 7
My euid and egid is: 1000,1000
Will move pid 3042 to cgroup 'qqq'
Adding controller memory
Warning: cannot write tid 3042 to /sys/fs/cgroup/qqq/cgroup.procs:Permission denied
Warning: cgroup_attach_task_pid failed: 50007
cgroup change of group failed
```

Comment: I was just trying this out but had no luck. My shell is running under cgroup user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-2.scope which is owned by root so I still get permission denied. I'm not sure how to get it to run under the user@1000.service cgroup instead which my user would have access to.